# SSRS command to change background colour

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report, using a matrix, that counts the number of opportunities created by type (columns) and by account manager (rows).

I would like to be able to change the colour of the background based on the event occurring in that day only.

The command I have used in the function option is this:

```
=iif(Fields!CreatedToday.Value="Yes" ANDALSO Fields!new_coreproductvendorname.Value="PCI ASV","PaleGreen","Transparent")
```

but it only picks out some of the correct values, seemingly only the most recent line in the dataset.

Is there a command that will iterate through the lines of the dataset to find rows where both criteria are met and return a true value?

I have attached the dataset and the current report output for reference.

[image: Dataset] & [image: Report]

Regards

Dave

Comment: There's not enough information here to determine what the issue is. One suggestion would be to add a calculated field to your dataset that is a flag for your condition `=IIf(Fields!CreatedToday.Value="Yes" AND Fields!new_coreproductvendorname.Value="PCI ASV", 1, Nothing)`. That way you can refer to that in your table and aggregate it if needed.

Comment: @StevenWhite I started with `AND` and changed to `ANDALSO`, it produces the same result. If I reorder the dataset it will always pull the first entry and then ignore the remainder

Comment: @StevenWhite I've edited the original question to include a couple of screenshots of the dataset and the report output